# JavaScript Remove Tag Not Working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the tag `<div id='parent'>` if no data is stored in the `<span id="test">`

It works perfectly in Chrome, but Firefox can not.

Is there a solution to fix this code?
If you must use jQuery, I am also ready.

**My Code:**

```
<h1>Result:</h1>
<div id='parent'>
<b>Age:</b> <span id='test'></span>
</div>

<script>
if ( document.getElementById('test').innerHTML == '' ){
document.getElementById('parent').remove();
}
</script>
```

Sample Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDesY.png

Sample Mozilla: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2SS1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to use jQuery then you can do this

```
if($("#test").html()==""){
    $("#parent").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Result:</h1>
<div id='parent'>
<b>Age:</b> <span id='test'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me

Comment: @Jonatan if it works for you, plz mark it as answer so it will help more users like you. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace this (see this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_removecurrent) and this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild))

```
document.getElementById('parent').remove();
```

by

```
currentNode = document.getElementById('parent').remove();
currentNode.parentNode().removeChild( currentNode );
```